# Could n't find com.iflex.fcat.drivers.jdbcx.base.BaseConnectionWrapper jar file

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, drivers

In my application i came across the following class which cause my build fail. I tried my best to include that jar in build path but didnt find any clue like in which jar this class exists. Can anybody let me know the jar file for the same. My application server is Websphere 8.5.5.2 and application is a java based.

**com.iflex.fcat.drivers.jdbcx.base.BaseConnectionWrapper**